# Eager fetching works in Onetomany and not working in Manytoone

Tags: jpa, groovy, one-to-many

This is something like mix of groovy and Java. I created the code as part of learning.

```
===================================================================

@Entity
public class GroovyBoy implements SimpleEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private long Id;
private String name;

@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private List<GroovyBro> brothers;

@Override
public Long getId() {
return Id;
}

@Override
public void setId(Long id) {
Id = id;
}
}

===================================================================

@Entity
class GroovyBro implements SimpleEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long Id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private GroovyBoy brother;

    @Override
    public Long getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    @Override
    public void setId(Long id) {
        Id = id
    }
}


===================================================================
        def dao = (MyDaoImpl) appContext.getBean("dao")

        def boy = new GroovyBoy()
        boy.name='boy1'

        def bro1 = new GroovyBro()
        bro1.name='bro1'

        def bro2 = new GroovyBro()
        bro2.name='bro2'

        boy.brothers = [bro1, bro2]

        dao.save(boy)

        //dao.evict(boy)

        println 'Id: ' + boy.brothers[0].id

        def loadBro = new GroovyBro();
        loadBro.id = boy.brothers[0].id

        GroovyBro bro = (GroovyBro) dao.get(loadBro)

        println 'Bro: ' + bro.brother

===================================================================
```

The last line is returning null. But when I fetch the GroovyBoy entity, it loads the persistent bag and then loads the GroovyBro instances.
Why is the GroovyBoy instance not loaded?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure what your code does, but ensure that you are setting both sides of the bi-directional relationship.

If when you created the object you only set one side, then the other side will still be null.

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the *owning* side of the relationship.  The owning side of the relationship corresponds to the table/class with the foreign key reference to the other, the @ManyToOne side.  It doesn't matter that you have set the non-owning side, which is what you are doing here:

```
boy.brothers = [bro1, bro2]

dao.save(boy)
```

When you call `dao.save(boy)`, your JPA provider is going to persist all of the mapped fields on your `GroovyBoy` instance, and then cascade the persist operation to each of the `GroovyBro` instances in its collection.  You have not set the `brother` property on either of your `GroovyBro` instances, so the foreign keys are set to null.  Therefore, when you load your `GroovyBro` instance here:

```
GroovyBro bro = (GroovyBro) dao.get(loadBro)
```

it correctly has a null reference for the `brother` property.  To fix, add:

```
bro1.brother = boy
bro2.brother = boy
```

before you call `dao.save(boy)`.

You can leave `boy.brothers = [bro1, bro2]`, but JPA isn't going to look at the contents of the collection in order to set the foreign key relationship.